# Django create a new column in an already existing table

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I'm using Django 3.0.5 and I am trying to create a new column in a table.

The table looks like this:

```py
class VacationModel(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    emp_id = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    from_date = models.DateField()
    to_date = models.DateField()
    reason = models.TextField()
    time_sent = models.DateTimeField("date sent")
    req_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
    req_denied = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
    # daysoff_given = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.emp_id
```

The new column would be `daysoff_given`. I tried adding this column and after running `python manage.py makemigrations` I got an error saying `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column`

I tried following some other answers and I deleted the migrations made inside the `migrations` folder, without deleting the `__init__.py` file. After running `makemigrations` again the same error occured and then I deleted the whole model and made a new model.

I think my database is broken, but is there an actual way to avoid this, since it has already happened two times.

Whenever I try to add a new column, it always throws that error and I cannot continue. How can I fix this?

Comment: "I deleted the migrations made inside the `migrations` folder"—why are so many people in a hurry to nuke their migrations? This is a _drastic_ step that should virtually _never_ be required. I hope you kept a copy around so you can put them back.

Comment: Did you _apply_ your new migration with `python manage.py migrate` after you created it?

Comment: @Chris Yes I applied the new migration after creating the model. The only change made was the `daysoff_given` field and the problem happened after running `makemigrations`

Comment: What do you mean by "after running `makemigrations`"? Did you get this error as part of running `makemigrations`? If not, what does "after" mean? What causes it to appear? And what is the full traceback of the error?

Comment: try deleting both the migrations and database then makemigrations and migrate. It should works

Comment: @riNg, did you read my first comment? _Deleting the migrations directory should **virtually never** be required._ Seriously, how did this become a go-to "solution" with Django? I see people recommending it all the time. And deleting the _database_ is even more drastic. Databases often contain _data_, and that data can be _important_. How is deleting your database an acceptable solution?

Comment: @Chris, just the database in development. It works for me all the time.

Comment: @riNg, it "works" by avoiding the problem. It's a *terrible* "solution" and an even worse habit. Please don't recommend it.

Comment: @riNg, in general, when you delete migrations (yes, even in development) and regenerate them you generate ones that aren't compatible with your _existing_ migrations. You know, for example, the ones already applied in production. What happens when your new migrations can't be applied cleanly to your _production_ database?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you created migrations but didn't apply them. Make sure you run both of the following commands after adding the column in the Model.

- `python manage.py makemigrations`
- `python manage.py migrate`

It it doesn't work, please edit your question and add the full trackback error to help us know what is the causing the error.